# how to htaccess redirect form www.mysite.com/* to www.mysite.com/

Tags: .htaccess

On my site google indexed `www.mysite.com/*` which isn't on my server.

This URL came from some other external source and it's causing a 404 error.

So I want to redirect this URL to my homepage.

How can I achive that?

Answer (score 1):

You could do a 301 redirect to your homepage. Search engines will then learn from this and eventually the listing will be removed.

Redirect 301 old-page.htm index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Add the following value to your .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Or .html is you're index is a .htm or .html file.

Comment: its .htm file but i dont want to redirect that url to home page using this method coz it ll replace my all 404 pages with homepage..which i dnt think good idea..so any other solution?